# Linebreaking gather (equation) environment?

Tags: equations, line-breaking, amsmath

Please help me to line break this `gather` environment. You can clearly see which line I want broken by where I've placed the `split` environment in my code. It's too long for 1 line.

I also want it tagged (i.e. $(20)$ or $(21)$ or whatever on the right). I'm using `gather` because I want all the equations to be aligned together by the LHS margin.

I use LaTeX.

[image]

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{gather}
  Q(CSAD_t(\tau)|\mathbf{Z}) = \alpha(\tau) + \beta(\tau)|R_{M,t}| + \gamma(\tau)R_{M,t}^2 + \epsilon_t \\
  \begin{split}
  Q(CSAD_t(\tau)|\mathbf{Z}) &= \alpha(\tau) + \beta(\tau)_0|R_{M,t}| + \gamma(\tau)_0R_{M,t}^2 + \beta(\tau)_1D_{ALL,t}|R_{M,t}| \\
  &+ \gamma(\tau)_1D_{ALL,t}R_{M,t}^2 + \epsilon_t \\ 
  \end{split} \newline
  Q(CSAD_t(\tau)|\mathbf{Z}) = \alpha(\tau) + \mathbf{\beta(\tau)}\mathbf{D}'|R_{M,t}| + \mathbf{\gamma(\tau)}\mathbf{D}'R_{M,t}^2 + \epsilon_t \\
  \mathbf{\beta(\tau)} = [\beta(\tau)_0, \beta(\tau)_1,...,\beta(\tau)_6];\textrm{   }\mathbf{\gamma(\tau)} = [\gamma(\tau)_0,\gamma(\tau)_1,...,\gamma(\tau)_6];\textrm{   }\mathbf{D} = [1, D_{1,t},...,D_{6,t}] \notag \\
  \tau = 0.05,0.1,0.5,0.9,0.95 \notag 
  \end{gather}

  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the numbers by setting the `equation` counter to *one less* than the first number you want, in this case 19.  You had a glitch after the `{split}` because you used `\newline`, which is a text and not a math command.  Don't mix the two!  I put in `\\` instead, and a `\notag` to suppress the number that would be there (going by your example).  Finally, I replaced your explicit spacing in the last few lines with an `{aligned}` subenvironment, which allows me to get the final equations lined up as well as automatically spread out.

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

  \begin{document}

  \setcounter{equation}{19}
  \begin{gather}
  Q(CSAD_t(\tau)|\mathbf{Z})
        = \alpha(\tau) + \beta(\tau)|R_{M,t}| + \gamma(\tau)R_{M,t}^2 + \epsilon_t \\
  \begin{aligned}
  Q(CSAD_t(\tau)|\mathbf{Z})
        &= \alpha(\tau) + \beta(\tau)_0|R_{M,t}| + \gamma(\tau)_0R_{M,t}^2 \\
        &+ \beta(\tau)_1D_{ALL,t}|R_{M,t}| + \gamma(\tau)_1D_{ALL,t}R_{M,t}^2 + \epsilon_t
  \end{aligned} \notag\\
  Q(CSAD_t(\tau)|\mathbf{Z})
        = \alpha(\tau) + \mathbf{\beta(\tau)}\mathbf{D}'|R_{M,t}| + \mathbf{\gamma(\tau)}\mathbf{D}'R_{M,t}^2 + \epsilon_t \\
    \begin{aligned}
  \mathbf{\beta(\tau)} &= [\beta(\tau)_0, \beta(\tau)_1,...,\beta(\tau)_6]; &
    \mathbf{\gamma(\tau)} &= [\gamma(\tau)_0,\gamma(\tau)_1,...,\gamma(\tau)_6];\notag\\
    \mathbf{D}& = [1, D_{1,t},...,D_{6,t}] &
  \tau &= 0.05,0.1,0.5,0.9,0.95 \notag 
\end{aligned}
  \end{gather}

  \end{document}
```